# How can I override config parameters in Flask config?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask config and I configure my app like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('yourapplication.Config')
```

My Config object is this:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    DB_USER = os.getenv("DB_USER", "db_user")
    DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD", "db_password")
    DB_HOST = os.getenv("DB_HOST", "localhost")  # 127.0.0.1"
    DB_PORT = os.getenv("DB_PORT", "5555")
    DB_SCHEMA = "my_schema"
    DB_DATABASE_NAME = "my_database"
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(
        DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE_NAME)
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

I run my app like so (using flask-script):

```
my_flask_app cmd1 arg1 arg2
```

I would like to do the following:

```
DEBUG=true DB_PORT=1234 my_flask_app cmd1 arg1 arg2
```

and override the 2 config parameters. I am wondering if there is already a way to override config parameters from the command line or if I should go and write some code?

**EDIT**: To clarify, I have several preset configs which inherit from 'Config(object)' like so:

```
class Dev(Config):
    pass

class Ua(Config):
    pass

class Prod(Config):
    DEBUG = False
```

My app defaults to 'Dev' config. It is easy to imagine a scenario in which you want to run 'UA' config but override the port like so:

```
FLASK_ENV=UA DB_PORT=1234 my_flask_app cmd1 arg1 arg2
```

'FLASK_ENV' will internally select the 'UA' config object but I'd like DB_PORT to be applied on top. Just wondering if there is an extension or someone has had any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a standard way of achieving this functionality or a library that adds this useful behaviour at present.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few ways for overriding.

**1)** using `config.from_envvar` + `config.cfg`. Example:

```
# test.py
import json

from flask import Flask, current_app


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    DB_PORT = 1234


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('test.Config')
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS', silent=True)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return json.dumps({
        'DEBUG': current_app.config['DEBUG'],
        'DB_PORT': current_app.config['DB_PORT'],
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`config.cfg`:

```
DB_PORT = 4321
DEBUG = False
```

Run our app: `python test.py` and open `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. You will see the default values of config:

```
{"DEBUG": true, "DB_PORT": 1234}
```

Now add path of `config.cfg` into `YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS` variable and restart app.

```
export YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS={full_path_to}/config.cfg
python test.py
# open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 
# you will see {"DEBUG": false, "DB_PORT": 4321}
```

**2)** Similar to the first way, but without `.cfg`. `test.py`:

```
import json
import os

from flask import Flask, current_app


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    DB_PORT = 1234


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    DB_PORT = 4321


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ.get('CONFIG_CLASS', 'test.Config'))
# route + run ...
```

How to check:

```
python test.py # open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ - default config
# ProductionConfig config
export CONFIG_CLASS=test.ProductionConfig
python test.py # open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ - production config
```

**3)** In some cases only env variables are sufficient.

> But be careful you can have problems with types

```
import json
import os

from flask import Flask, current_app


class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    DB_PORT = 1234


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('test.Config')
app.config.update({
    'DB_PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', Config.DB_PORT)
    # you should to set type of variable here
    # DB_PORT will be string
    # 'DB_PORT': int(os.environ.get('DB_PORT', Config.DB_PORT))
})
# route + run ...
```

Let's check:

```
export DB_PORT=4321
python test.py
```

Open http://127.0.0.1:5000/ you will see that `DB_PORT` was changed but is not integer. So this is a good solution for some settings and for specific cases. I think that 1 and 2 ways are better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the main trick is converting shell objects to python objects correctly. I haven't spent much time thinking about this but I think parsing the values as json might work well in converting the command line values to correct python objects